# create image gallery in jQuery with next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on asp.net mvc web application, in which I am using image upload functionality.

In this functionality, I want to display Image gallery of uploaded images to user with next and previous buttons.

Is anyone have idea how to do it in simple jQuery or JavaScript?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do not re-invent the wheel. try one of these http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

Comment: are you looking for a Jquery image slideshow plugin ?

Comment: @surendran: yes i am ok with Jquery image slideshow plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of Jquery image slideshow plugins available please check http://goo.gl/UXvJQ

Comment: i am lookking for any free jQuery image slider..:)

Comment: check http://goo.gl/eDcNI this it is free and responsive too.
also http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/ . Try googling you will get lot more.